# 404 Error with ui.tags.video in shiny for python

Tags: python, py-shiny

This is so simple, I can't figure what could be wrong. I have a python file and a file named test.mp4 in the same directory, and am running the script from the same directory. Never-the-less, the line `ui.tags.video(src="test.mp4")` gives a `"GET /test.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found` error.

Any idea? It's not a big deal right now for me as I don't need to do it. I'm just going through all the docs on posit and hit this problem so I'm curious.

Comment: Well, later in the docs I found that I need to create a www directory and store it there. Not sure why my question offended someone.